# Find a document in a nested query mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, shell, nested, find

I have two collection A and B where in B there is a field that has the id of A as shown in the below. The code below returns nothing.

So I am trying to figure out if I want to use mongodb shell, how can I use the return cursor of A in order to point to ID values and send it to the value of `AID` key.

```javascript
db.B.find({
   'AID': db.A.find({'item': 'x'},
                    {'id':     1})
});
```

Comment: Can you add an example with an input and the desired output?

Comment: made code more readable